# How to join multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my codes:

```
public function getallcontractfiles()
{
    $this->db->select('cd.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cf.Contract_File_Name) AS fileslink');         
    $this->db->from('contract_details as cd');
    $this->db->join('contract_files as cf', 'cd.Contract_Id = cf.Contract_Id','LEFT'); 

    if($this->session->userdata['user_type'] == 'ADMIN' && $this->session->userdata['user_group'] == '' ){
        $this->db->where('cd.Company_id',$this->session->userdata['company_id']);
        }
    if($this->session->userdata['user_type'] == 'USER'){
    $this->db->where('cd.users_id',$this->session->userdata['logged_user']);
    }
     $this->db->group_by('cd.Contract_Id '); 
    $this->db->order_by('cd.Contract_Id', 'desc');
     $query = $this->db->get();
    // print_r($this->db->last_query()); die;

        if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $row){
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
            return $rows;
        }
}
```

My question is: I have also a table called company and my App is all about to print out all contracts files with their companies. I have defined Company_id as a foreign key in Contract_files.
Please help me to join company table to this function.
Thank you.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT seems rather contrary to the entire enterprise

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your ORM but this should make sense:

```
$this->db->join('company', 'cf.Company_id = company.Company_Id','INNER');
```

Right after your join with contract_files table, Also specify fields you want to retrieve in the from company table as well.

**UPDATE**

Since your query is bringing up multiple contract files then you will have to do the same with company table as every contract file could have many companies, If they all have the same company, Then the foreign key Company_id should be in contract_details table.

**IMPORTANT**

GROUP_CONCAT() has a limitation of 1024 by default, So it's not the best idea to put files names in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getallcontractfiles(){
$this->db->select('cd.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cf.Contract_File_Name) AS fileslink');         
$this->db->from('contract_details as cd');
$this->db->join('contract_files as cf', 'cd.Contract_Id = cf.Contract_Id'); 

if($this->session->userdata('user_type') == 'ADMIN' && $this->session->userdata('user_group') == '' ){
    $this->db->where('cd.Company_id',$this->session->userdata('company_id'));
    }
if($this->session->userdata('user_type') == 'USER'){
$this->db->where('cd.users_id',$this->session->userdata('logged_user'));
}
 $this->db->group_by('cd.Contract_Id '); 
$this->db->order_by('cd.Contract_Id', 'desc');
 $query = $this->db->get();
// print_r($this->db->last_query()); die;

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

Try This  Code.

Answer (score -1):

LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;

RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;

INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would advise you edit this answer to provide some narrative to distinguish between the three types of join you have proposed (given that the questioner is clearly new to sql).